# Profile picture in ionic ios mobile application getting disappeared after application restart

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have used cordova plugin camera to set profile picture in my mobile application. When I start my application and set profile picture it is saves and displays properly but when I close my application and restart it then image is not showing in that div. This happens in case of ios only,  in Android it is working properly

Comment: Can you share the code ? Also, does your profile picture is stored online ? Or do you just store it locally ? Please answer by editing your question

Comment: On click of open gallery i am calling OpenGallery()  function

Comment: $scope. OpenGallery = function () {navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
{
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
}); }

Comment: Can you edit the question ? And format it correctly. It is not readable in comments.